# Fastest way of look up big tables across servers?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Scenario: An SSIS package, running on server A, is pulling data into SQL Server from a remote server X, which might be DB2, Oracle or so; **network cost between A and X is not low**, and the job only have read permission on X.

The query I want to use to pull data is to refine record based on most recent one on same business key, i.e.,

```
SELECT X.*
FROM A.table a
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY business_key ORDER BY update_date DESC)
   FROM X.table x ) x
ON x.rn = 1 AND a.business_key =x.business_key
WHERE a.id <> x.id
```

Typical lookup set on A is 10M row, and the table on X is around 100M, but due to query design, the row returned mostly are less than 10K.

Given no write permission on X (this includes create temp table), what's the best way of designing SSIS data flow to make it feasible and having a lowest network cost?

Answer (score 0):

For your version, `X` will pass `(J+1) * 100M` cells to `A`.

- Assume there are J number of fields in table x.
- Assume there are K rows of rn = 1.
- Final result `10K` row, table a `10M` row, table x `100M`.
  row.
- There should only be `J * 10K` cells at final result.

If you need so many fields in x, here may be another method.

```
CREATE TABLE A.table axax
AS
(SELECT x.business_key
FROM A.table a
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT business_key, id
    FROM (SELECT business_key, id, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY business_key ORDER BY update_date DESC)
          FROM X.table x)
    WHERE rn = 1) AS x
ON a.business_key = x.business_key
WHERE a.id <> x.id);

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
     FROM (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY business_key ORDER BY update_date DESC)
          FROM X.table x)
     WHERE rn = 1)
AND business_key IN (SELECT business_key FROM A.table axax);
```

`CREATE TABLE` : `X` will pass `2 * K` cells to `A`.

`SELECT *` : `A` will pass `1 * K` cells to `X`, then `X` will pass final result `J * 10K` cells to you.

Of course you can combine these two statement in to one if you do not have write permission on `A`.

(I am not quite sure how they pass the SQL/commond in between.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, data received from **X** can be filtered only by **X's** own data. Reason - SSIS runs on server **A**, data from **A** is not available on **X**.
According to your query design, you need the latest data from **X** not matching business key from **A**.
Data Flow design is as follows:

1. OLE DB Source - query **X** data with filter `RN=1`.
2. Lookup **A** data by business key, directing unmatched rows to special output, and discard matched entries.
3. Do further processing and save data.

It seems the lightest method concerning traffic from **X**, since you cannot have data from **A** on **X** due to your access rights limitations.

Comment: I thought about this design, however since I must run package on server A, will majority of data (`RN=1` cannot filter many) still be read from X to A for SSIS to make join condition?